# Adding metadata to jsTree

Tags: json, metadata, jstree

I just can not figure this out, or find any docs.

I have a bare-bones JSON:

{
  "data": "node",
  "metadata" : { "content": "hellooooo" }
}

This gets loaded, but I can not figure out how to write to this field, retrieve this field, and ensure that it is made when a new node is created.

Where are the docs for metadata?

Thanks,
Marco.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer at http://groups.google.com/group/jstree/browse_thread/thread/28d0c8d3eb2d9f8f

> if you're using JSON and you deliver
>   your nodes with a metadata like this:

```
{
"data":  "This is the name of the node",
"metadata": {
     "number": "no1",
     "description": "Description"
  }
}
```

> ...you'll be able to get (and set) the
>   data like this:

```
$('div#jstree').jstree(
/*  ...options...  */
).bind('select_node.jstree',
function(e, data){
     alert(  $(data.rslt.obj).data('description') 
 ); });
```

> This works with the newest commit
>   (rc3/r233). In older versions it uses

```
$(data.rslt.obj).data("jstree").description
```

The last solution worked for me (the default download for now is rc2).

Comment: I keep getting `data.rslt` as undefined

Comment: I can't get this to work. I'm sending data to my nodes through an AJAX call -- do I need a different `data` node and `metadata` node in the JSON? I was able to create the tree structure with id's and children without a root `data` object in the JSON i.e. just `{"id" : "3", "children" : [...]}`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, I was losing my mind over that. None of the old examples worked!
So I finally can access metadata, the problem is that I don't know how to iterate over unknown number of metadata fields?

ok, now I have checked it and it possible to iterate over object returned by data() with no named parameters

```
.bind("select_node.jstree", function (e, data) {
    var propsObj = $(data.rslt.obj).data();
    for (var prop in propsObj) { 
       alert(prop + " = " + propsObj[prop] + "\n"); 
    }  
});
```

If you need to avoid jstree_children Array getting in your way, the best way in my opinion is to encapsulate metadata into another object like so:

```
"metadata" : {"properties" : {"prop1" : "aa1a", "prop2" : "123"}}
```

then you can iterate using:

```
var metadata = $(data.rslt.obj).data();
for (var prop in metadata.properties) {...}
```